# webrtc on ios ,how to realize the video function?

Tags: ios, video, webrtc

i am coding the webrtc on ios ,i build the source code and generates a static library. According to the official demo, realizing the function of audio， but i don`t know how to realize the video on ios, who can help me or give me a  demo obout video use webrtc, thanks .